# Magento 1.9 category filter not working based on store id

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using the following code to filter the category based on store id and custom attribute, but its not working..

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()

                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                    ->addIsActiveFilter()   
                    ->setStoreId(1)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array('notnull' => true))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array('neq' => '')) 
                    ->getAllIds();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to get ID of collection.

Then try this.

```
 $category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                //->getCollection()

                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                ->addIsActiveFilter()   
                ->setStoreId(1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array('notnull' => true))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', array('neq' => ''))
                ->getAllIds()
                ;
```

Comment: I dont have any luck from the above changes.., any other idea or suggestion?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Getting the following error..
 /var/www/html/sports/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/ddevs/example_core_block.phtml(11): Varien_Object->__call('addAttributeToS...', Array)

Comment: did you comment out `getCollection()`? also comment `addAttributeToSelect('*')`

Comment: there is no real difference between `getCollection` and calling the resource model. `getCollection` returns an instance of that resource class